# Updating a path before Animating it in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to animate my path with a move value, It works almost, but the needed update to path happens after animation is done! Which must happen before Animation! How can I make it possible?

***PS: The issue is about Path, and I am trying solve it through path.***

```
struct HatchedShap: Shape {
    
    let dis: CGFloat
    var move: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return move }
        set { move = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in

            for index in -Int(move*2.0)...Int((rect.height)/dis) {
                
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + (CGFloat(index) + move)*dis))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + (CGFloat(index) + move)*dis))
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var move: CGFloat = CGFloat()

    var body: some View {

        HatchedShap(dis: 20.0, move: move)
            .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.0))
            .background(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
            .onTapGesture {
  
                if (move == -0.5) { move = 0}
                else { move = -0.5 }
            }
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0), value: move)

    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using [`stride(from:through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride) is much easier. You can then `continue` with the loop if it is out of the range of the `rect`. This example also nicely wraps around if the factor's absolute value is greater than 1.

Code:

```
struct HatchedShap: Shape {
    let dis: CGFloat
    var move: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return move }
        set { move = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            for start in stride(from: 0, through: rect.height, by: dis) {
                let offset = start + dis * move.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)
                guard 0 ... rect.height ~= offset else {
                    continue
                }

                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + offset))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + offset))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

| Factor of `-0.5` | Factor of `-2` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Factor of -0.5] | [image: Factor of -2] |

---

Small note:

You can simplify:

```
if (move == -0.5) {
    move = 0
} else {
    move = -0.5
}
```

To the following, which removes duplication & possibly faster because there is no branching (depends on if the compiler optimizes this):

```
move = -0.5 - move
```

Comment: @swiftPunk Yeah the `-2` is just to demo it wraps around for larger magnitudes. It moves faster because you do an animation in the same amount of time, but moves a larger distance. Ideally you would scale the animation duration by `move`, too. But if it will _always_ by `-0.5` here, there's no need.

Comment: I have problem to understand the part of `.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: dis)` I know it is correct and needed, but I cannot follow why. Could you explain it in simple way plz?

Comment: The offset is just `start + dis * move`, however we want to do the modulus of `dis * move`. For example, if `move` was 1.5, it would be the equivalent of `move` being 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

In your `path` code, assign `y` to a `let` constant and check to make sure it is larger than `0` before adding the line to the path:

```
struct HatchedShap: Shape {
    
    let dis: CGFloat
    var move: CGFloat
    
    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return move }
        set { move = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return Path { path in

            for index in -Int(move*2.0)...Int((rect.height)/dis) {
                let y = rect.minY + (CGFloat(index) + move)*dis
                if y > 0 {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: y))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + (CGFloat(index) + move)*dis))
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```